# Calculating performance based on Θ (nlogn)

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting

How should I get started for the following problem?

> A wood-chunk requires 20 seconds to chunk 60 chunks of wood, but runs an algorithm with temporal asymptotic performance Θ(nlogn). How many time is required for the wood-chunk to chunk 5000 chunks of wood?

I wasn't sure how to proceed this problem since I don't know any info about the function `g(n)` for `Θ(g(n))`.

It is from my c++ class exercise sheet under the chapter of Arrays, Searching, and Sorting.

Comment: The best I can say is "probably more than 15000, but maybe not". Where does this problem appear? Do you have a link? It seems a badly posed problem; some context is needed to see if the asker wants a "hand-waving" answer or a strict one.

Comment: The person who wrote this problem does not seem to understand big-O (or big Theta) notation.

Comment: @interjay Or woodchucks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be determined from the data in the question.

The concept of "asymptotical performance" and the designation Θ(nlogn) talk about the running time of algorithms for `n` greater than some unknown constant (typically denoted by `N`). That is:

> There exist constants `N`, `c1` and `c2` such that for each `n` greater than `N`, the running time `T(n)` satisfies `c1 * n * log(n) < T(n) < c2 * n * log(n)`.

However, you don't know the value of N, so you don't know whether 60 or 5000 are greater than `N`.